# Populating listbox from csv via list<>

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, listbox

Like the title suggests, I'm trying to populate a listbox in a WPF application with information from a csv. Ideally, I want to display every line from the csv, but only certain columns i.e. with fitness data, I would have a first name, last name, DOB, gender, etc. but I would only display first and last name. My code is as follows:

```
public partial class PatientList : Window
{
    int x = 0;
    public PatientList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HumanResources ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
        List<PatientInformation> AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();

        foreach (PatientInformation PatientChoice in AllPatients)
        {
            lboxPatients.Items.Add(AllPatients[x]);
            x += 1;
        }
    }
```

Human Resources class

```
public List<PatientInformation> PopPatientList()
    {
        DataAccess PatientList4Doc = new DataAccess();
        List<PatientInformation> DocsPatients = PatientList4Doc.ListofPatients();
        return DocsPatients;
    }
```

Data Access Class

```
 class DataAccess
{
    public List<PatientInformation> ListofPatients()
    {
        List<PatientInformation> ListofPatients = new List<PatientInformation>();
        string[] UserData = File.ReadAllLines("UserList.csv");

        foreach (string Person in UserData)
        {
            string[] PersonInfo = Person.Split(',');
            PatientInformation Patient = new PatientInformation()
            {
                Username = PersonInfo[0].ToUpper(),
                LastName = PersonInfo[1],
                FirstName = PersonInfo[2],
                DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(PersonInfo[3]),
                Gender = Convert.ToChar(PersonInfo[4]),
                Height = Convert.ToInt16(PersonInfo[5]),
                Weight = Convert.ToInt16(PersonInfo[6]),
                CaloricIntake = PersonInfo[7],
                WaterDrank = PersonInfo[8],
                CaloriesBurned = PersonInfo[9],
                TimeSlept = PersonInfo[10],
                ContextMessage = PersonInfo[11],
                Replymessage = PersonInfo[12]
            };
            ListofPatients.Add(Patient);
        }
        return ListofPatients;
    }
```

Patient Information Class

```
 public class PatientInformation
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string CaloricIntake { get; set; }
    public string WaterDrank { get; set; }
    public string CaloriesBurned { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlept { get; set; }
    public string ContextMessage { get; set; }
    public string Replymessage { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine up until I attempt to populate the listbox. When I try to read the information in, all I get is the code path instead of the desired information. My question is: Once I have all the information pulled in from the CSV, how can I then print it to the listbox and have it show stuff from PatientInformation? Thanks in advance for any help

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMx0D.jpg)

**EDIT**

@Hypnos: I implemented your suggestion like so:

```
I tried implementing your example like so:  HumanResources ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
        List<PatientInformation> AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();
        List<PatientInformation> p = new List<PatientInformation>();
        p.Add(new PatientInformation() { Username = Convert.ToString(AllPatients[0]), FirstName = Convert.ToString(AllPatients[2]), LastName = Convert.ToString(AllPatients[1]) });

        lboxPatients.ItemsSource = p;
```

However, this returns an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListBox has no concept of columns so I guess you want to display simple lines of strings in it. You could then simply add strings to the Items collection:

```
    public PatientList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HumanResources ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
        List<PatientInformation> AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();

        foreach (PatientInformation PatientChoice in AllPatients)
        {
            lboxPatients.Items.Add(string.Format("{0};{1}", PatientChoice.FirstName, PatientChoice.LastName));
        }
    }
```

If you want to display actual columns with headers you could use a ListView:

```
     <ListView x:Name="lv">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    public PatientList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HumanResources ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
        List<PatientInformation> AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();
        lv.ItemsSource = AllPatients;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should customize your ListItem DataTemplate.
Look at that sample:

In code behind, for practical reasons, i create a new List, adding an entry in it

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<PatientInformation> p = new List<PatientInformation>();
        p.Add(new PatientInformation() { Username = "John", FirstName ="John", LastName = "Doe" });

        listBox.ItemsSource = p;
    }
```

XAML side, to view the particular fields, we could do a thing like that:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Margin="10,10,0,0" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

As you can see, apart from the DataContext = {Binding} on the listBox itself, i've created a customized DataTemplate for ListItem(s), in order to redirect the binding to its properties, on the controls i wish to.
In my case, two TextBlocks which will expose the FirstName and the LastName properties.

Hope this helps